# How to merge two JSON under an Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I get details from the user through HTML form, and onclick the form submission, I run the php file, save2json.php, which retrieves from HTML form, and posts it as JSON in the file appointments.json.

**save2json.php**

```
$formdata = array(
  $_POST['doctor'] => array(
    'name'=> $_POST['name'],
    'phone'=> $_POST['phone'],       
    'bday'=> $_POST['bday'],
    'datepicker'=> $_POST['datepicker'],
  )
);    

$filetxt = 'appointments.json';    
$arr_data = array();       
if(file_exists($filetxt))
{          
  $jsondata = file_get_contents($filetxt); 
  $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
}           
$arr_data[] = $formdata;
$jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);    
if(file_put_contents('appointments.json', $jsondata))
```

**What I get:** *[appointments.json]*

```
[{
    "Doctor #3": {
        "name": "0",
        "phone": "0",
        "bday": "0",
        "datepicker": "0"
    }
}, {
    "Doctor #3": {
        "name": "1",
        "phone": "1",
        "bday": "1",
        "datepicker": "1"
    }
}, {
    "Doctor #1": {
        "name": "2",
        "phone": "2",
        "bday": "2",
        "datepicker": "2"
    }
}, {
    "Doctor #2": {
        "name": "3",
        "phone": "3",
        "bday": "3",
        "datepicker": "3"
    }
}]
```

**What I want:** *[appointments.json]*

```
[{
    "Doctor #3": [{
            "name": "0",
            "phone": "0",
            "bday": "0",
            "datepicker": "0"
        },

        {
            "name": "1",
            "phone": "1",
            "bday": "1",
            "datepicker": "1"
        }
    ],
    "Doctor #1": {
        "name": "2",
        "phone": "2",
        "bday": "2",
        "datepicker": "2"
    },
    "Doctor #2": {
        "name": "3",
        "phone": "3",
        "bday": "3",
        "datepicker": "3"
    }

}]
```

If it is under same doctor, I want to make both objects come under the same array. And if it isn't like Doctor 1 and Doctor 2, in this case, I want them as separate apart from Doctor 3 array.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: There's no such thing as JSON Objects. `:)`

Comment: You need to either change the layout to array format for all the doctor `id`s or it will be really difficult. Do you wanna change it to that way?

Comment: Oops. I'm sorry. I'm not aware of the terms, it's quite confusing. Sorry again.

Comment: It has to come under same Doctor, array doesn't matter. If it comes under same doctor, it's fine.

Comment: Oh yeah sure.. I have a solution.

Comment: I am using this JSON to get a listview in Android, followed this tut: http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/08/android-json-parse-remote-url.html
It was mentioned as JSON object here. What's it called when it's enclosed between {}?

Comment: Okay, so if that's the case, you need to do it this way... See that.

Comment: Does it work boss? Macha seekaram sollu da... `:D`

Comment: xD :P Thanks for the solution. Unfortunately, same result
Added this if (isset($arr_data[$_POST['doctor']]))
    $arr_data[$_POST['doctor']][] = $_POST['doctor']; before encoding. 

http://www.exceptnothing.com/appointment.html - Create appointments here. http://www.exceptnothing.com/appointments.json - View it here.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first attempt to put it inside the `doctor` array key:

```
<?php
    // build the array
    $docDetails = array(
        'name'=> $_POST['name'],
        'phone'=> $_POST['phone'],
        'bday'=> $_POST['bday'],
        'datepicker'=> $_POST['datepicker'],
    );

    // get the file's content as an array.
    $filetxt = 'appointments.json';
    if(file_exists($filetxt))
        $arr_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($filetxt), true);
    else
        $arr_data = array();
    $arr_data[$_POST['doctor']][] = $docDetails;
?>
```